# Can I have an SVN Repo as a source for a GIT Repo

Tags: git, svn, migration

I have a project in an SVN source, which will have to be migrated to a Git repository. What I'd like to do is committing all changes to Git repo from now on, while still fetching eventual changes from SVN, until it's dismissed.

At the moment, I created the Git Repo, used `git svn` to clone it from the original SVN and pushed everything into Git. Issue is, if I do a Pull, I'm fetching the modifications from Git, which is not what I want.

In practice, I'm trying to "fork" the SVN repository into Git and tracking SVN changes. Is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Why, oh why would you want to do this?  What's the reason for the unnecessary complexity?

Comment: Simply because we'll be moving to Git, but there are 3rd parties involved who won't do it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that, in your git repo, the `master` branch is tracking `git-svn` so when you run `git svn rebase` it updates `master` with the content in SVN.
In this same repository you can have another branch which merges regularly `master` but contains modifications that will not be sent back to SVN.

While migrating from svn to git we have the same workflow than described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4238528/592392).

Comment: So `git svn rebase` is the equivalente of an `svn update`? And will commits all end up in Git, not in SVN? Sorry if I'm asking something basic, I'm very new to Git and I still don't know it well.

Comment: its the equivalent yes, and all commits in the `master` branch (or the one tracking `git-svn`) will end up in svn when you run `git svn dcommit`. The reality is a little bit more complex, you will need to read detailed articles like http://andy.delcambre.com/2008/03/04/git-svn-workflow.html if you are using it in a development team, its quite critical.

Comment: Ok. I don't actually want to commit anything to SVN anymore, only 3rd parties will do it using their SVN tools. Therefore, if I understood it correctly, I could go on with `git svn rebase` to get their updates, then `git commit` and `git push` to send them to my Git repo. Would that be correct?

Comment: `git svn rebase` will copy the SVN commits to your `master` branch, then you can `push` this `master` branch to your git repository (there is no need to commit, `git svn rebase` will create a git commit per svn commit)

Comment: Ok, perfect. That's exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: @Diego `git-svn-rebase` will modify the history of `master`. You won't be able to push without `-f`. You need a separate `svn` branch, which represents upstream `svn` changes, and then continually merge that into `master`

Comment: @alternative That's ok to me. The SVN Team and I will be working on different and independent parts of the project, there will be no clashes anyway. What I could probably do is branching my part while I keep "rebasing" with SVN, then merge my changes into the master and push. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is `git svn rebase`, as mentioned, which will allow you to get upstream changes from `svn`.

Note that there is currently a GSoC project for adding svn remotes. Its on its fifth version of the patch series at the moment.

`git svn rebase` will cause you extreme problems, though, for example if you push to a public repository and `git svn rebase`. For this reason you cannot push changes not in `svn` to the main `git` repository.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Git while letting 3rd parties to use your SVN repository, you can simply use any transparent Git<->SVN gateway, like [SubGit](http://subgit.com). You will continue with Git forgetting about SVN, and SVN-users will never know you have a Git interface.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, but we already have an infrastructure in place. However, I'll surely take note of your suggestion, it may come handy in the future.