# Git: find new cherries

Tags: git, svn, cherry-pick

I've set up a process, based on [Adam Spiers' answer in a previous SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924001), to periodically publish a Git repository to a path in an SVN repository.  Everything is working quite well, but there's one piece I haven't figured out.  When I'm grabbing subsequent Git changes using `cherry-pick`, how do I figure out which new changes have occurred on this Git side, needing to be cherry-picked into the SVN side?

To be more specific, after I do the initial push of the Git history into SVN, I'm now sitting on a `master` branch which has the same content & patch history as the Git origin, but it's diverged from `origin/master` for basically its full history:

```
% git --no-pager diff master git-svn
% git status
# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 3 and 2 different commit(s) each, respectively.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Now, I do a fetch of new upstream changes:

```
% git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From /cygdrive/c/foo/git/testrep
   6d7dd94..08d3d19  master     -> origin/master
```

At this point, I need to figure out which revisions need to be cherry-picked, then I'll cherry-pick them and do a `git svn dcommit`.  But I can't figure out how to get that list of cherries.  I've tried various `git cherry` commands, and both `git cherry origin master` and `git cherry master origin` report long lists of basically every change on each side.

Should I resort to parsing the last cherry-pick out of the log file?  I'm using `git cherry-pick -x`, so I do have a record there.

Comment: Have you tried a simple `rebase --onto`? Git should be clever enough to figure out patch-equivalent commits and drop everything that was already picked for your SVN branch.

Comment: I'm not seeing it work - if I do `git fetch origin` and then `git rebase --onto git-svn origin`, nothing seems to happen, when I'd expect to see 2 new commits rebased.  Also, would that approach get unwieldy if I have hundreds/thousands of commits?

Comment: Try something along the lines of `git rebase --onto git-svn <last picked/rebased  commit from origin/master> <origin/master>`. Maybe combine with `-i/--interactive`

Comment: It would help HUGELY if you could provide a reduced test case.

Comment: @Adam, do you mean an actual repo to look at?  I think all the steps I've performed are here and in the previous thread.

Comment: I mean all the steps starting from zero repos through to reproducing the problem.  You never gave details of how the merge commits are created, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I have a solution - after every `git cherry-pick` ... `git svn dcommit` round, I do a `git tag -f last-picked origin`.  Then next time, I can cherry pick from `last-picked` to `origin`.

I'm willing to mark someone's answer as accepted if they have a better solution, but at this point it looks like I don't necessarily need another answer.