# What is a smarter way to "reset" a dev branch in Git?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I have a `master` and `dev` branches. Whenever I merge `dev` into `master` I *have* to use the `--no-ff` (no fast-forward) method. What I do at the moment, after merging:

- delete `dev`
- start a new `dev` branch from `master`

This allows me to continue the development on `dev` after the merge. Is there a smarter/shorter way to do it?

### Edit:

Simply continuing to commit to `dev` and merge to `master` yields the following graph:

```
git log --oneline --graph --branches 
*   62d400f Second Merge branch 'dev'
|\  
| * 86cd761 Continue 2 dev after merge
| * b10e96b Continue dev after merge
* |   04dcd00 Merge branch 'dev'
|\ \  
| |/  
| * 80d5577 Continue dev
| * 7119020 Started to dev file
|/  
* 05350a5 Updated the file
* 9e70af0 Initial commit
```

However, if I delete `dev` and then branch again from `master`, I can have the following graph:

```
*   c39c881 Third Merge branch 'dev'
|\  
| * cab5dc5 Back on (new) dev
|/  
*   62d400f Second Merge branch 'dev'
|\  
| * 86cd761 Continue 2 dev after merge
| * b10e96b Continue dev after merge
* |   04dcd00 Merge branch 'dev'
|\ \  
| |/  
| * 80d5577 Continue dev
| * 7119020 Started to dev file
|/  
* 05350a5 Updated the file
* 9e70af0 Initial commit
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this looks cleaner, isn't it? That's why I, naively, delete and re-branch from `master`.

As for why I have this approach in the first place: my `master` is basically an SVN where I'm allowed only certain commit messages (and thus limited number of commits). So I develop on `dev` and when I'm ready I merge to master and leave the proper commit message.

### Context:

I use the workflow described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4238528/671013). I somehow realized that I have to delete `dev` and re-branch from `master` after I push the changes to SVN.

Comment: Why do you have to do this?

Comment: First why do you need --no-ff? and second, what is wrong about creating a new branch for a new feautre? that should be the way to go. If you call your branch with a name regarding the task you will see that it makes sense

Comment: I must have clean merges into master. All the development is carried out in `dev`. I branch from `dev` for feature, then merge back to `dev`. When I'm ready, I merge to `master`. I have to keep the merges visible in the history.

Comment: @Dror - but why do you need to destroy the dev branch and recreate it? What you have descirbed is a typical gitflow, have a read: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow. No branch removing is required.

Comment: But why? Are there any non-technical reasons to do it? If you want to mark place, where branch dev was merged into master history, then maybe tags are better solution?

Comment: Personally I like the --no-ff option.  As the others mention, I don't see why you are deleting and recreating dev though - you should be able to just continue on with it.

Comment: Do you mean "rest", or "reset"?

Comment: @AndrewC: See my update. Simply continuing the development on `dev` yields a messy graph.

Comment: You could certainly argue aesthetics for that particular case.  Given enough time, developers, and branches though and it probably doesn't make a difference in the long run.

Comment: Are you rebasing *dev* onto *master* before merging and using `git-svn rebase`? I don't understand why your history keeps re-merging the same commits, and I feel like there's something in your workflow that's not in your question.

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

In Git, a branch named *dev* that points to a given commit (e.g. cf2308e) is still the same branch, even if you delete it and re-create it. The branch name holds the reference to a commit; Git doesn't carry around any other branch-related history, so what you're doing isn't inherently useful to Git or to you.

### Continue After Merging

> I have a master and dev branches. Whenever I merge dev into master I have to use the --no-ff (no fast forward) method.

Typically one does this when they want to force a merge commit rather than a fast-forward. Some shops like to do this to track merges from a branch within commit messages, since Git commits don't actually carry any branch information. In Git, branch membership is inferred from the ancestry of the commits, rather than stored as explicit data like it is in some other distributed version control systems.

However, there's no useful reason to actually delete the merged branch to "reset dev." You can continue developing on the *dev* branch, and Git will be smart enough not to re-merge the same commits the next time you merge with *master*.

Deleting and recreating *dev* doesn't really buy you anything if you're simply going to branch off the tip of *master* again. Since you aren't using topic branches with useful names, and you aren't doing squashed commits, my advice is to simply continue forward on *dev* after merging with *master*.

### Resetting a Branch

The only real use case for doing this is if you are merging something other than the tip of the *dev* branch. In that case, you may want to discard anything from *dev* that isn't already on *master*. If that's the case:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff <some_commit>

git checkout dev
git reset --hard master
git push --force origin dev
```

Note that if you rewind the tip of your branch, you'll likely have to force-push in order to reset the branch pointer on your remote. Rewinding will also force anyone pulling from you, or from a blessed repository, to re-clone or perform a forced reset of the *dev* branch too. For example:

```
git checkout dev
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/dev
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to delete `dev` and re-create if from `master`, you can simply `git reset --hard master` while on your `dev` branch.